# Update DLL thats in use with Prism during runtime

Tags: c#, dll, prism, updates

I need to update a dll that has been loaded in to my project that is using prism. I am of course getting the "Cannot access file" "file in use" exception when I try to copy over the updated version of the dll at runtime. Is there any way to update dlls that are loaded into the project without shutting down the project and restarting it?

Ive seen some things on AppDomain with remoting is this the path ill need to take if its possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is turn on Shadow Copying at the app domain level.  This is a .net feature rather than a Prism feature.  I use it in my Prism app and it works quite well.

This link: [Using Shadow Copying](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29961/Shadow-Copying-of-Applications) has a useful practical article about how to use this.

If you're using .Net 4.0 or above you'll want to add the following to your App.config as it speeds up the startup file compare significantly

```
<configuration>
<runtime>
  <shadowCopyVerifyByTimestamp enabled="true"/>
</runtime>
```